# What is the explicit ${\rm GL}_n$-action on the Weyl algebra?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, group-actions, differential-operators, invariant-theory

This is a typical classical invariant theory setup.  Let $V = \mathbb C^n$, and let $\mathbb C[V] \cong \mathbb C[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be the space of polynomial functions on $V$.  The group $G={\rm GL}(n,\mathbb C)$ acts on $V$ in the obvious way, inducing the usual action on $\mathbb C[V]$ via $(g \cdot f)(v) = f(g^{-1}v)$ for $g \in G$, $f \in \mathbb C[V]$, and $v \in V$.  Hence $G \subset {\rm End}(\mathbb C[V])$.

Now consider the Weyl algebra $\mathbb D(V)$ consisting of polynomial-coefficient differential operators on $\mathbb C[V]$.  Clearly $\mathbb D(V) \subset {\rm End}(\mathbb C[V])$ as well, and in fact $G$ normalizes $\mathbb D(V)$; that is, we have a group action of $G$ on $\mathbb D(V)$ given by
$$
g \cdot D = g \circ D \circ g^{-1} \in \mathbb D(V),
$$ for $g \in G$ and $D \in \mathbb D(V)$.  Given the action above, I have seen several sources state without proof that the $G$-action on the span of the differential operators $\partial_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \in \mathbb D(V)$ is equivalent to the defining representation $V$, whereas the $G$-action on the span of the multiplication operators $x_i \in \mathbb D(V)$ is equivalent to the dual $V^*$.

This has been driving me insane; below is my attempt to convince myself of this fact, using a concrete example.  Is this the correct way to think about the actions here?  Or, is there a more obvious way to see it?

**Example.** Let $n=2$, so that $\mathbb C[V] = \mathbb C[x,y]$, and $\mathbb D(V)$ is generated by the set $\{x,y,\partial_x, \partial_y\}$.  Consider $g=\left[ \begin{smallmatrix} 3 & 5\\1 & 2 \end{smallmatrix}\right] \in G$, so that $g^{-1} = \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} \phantom{-}2 & -5\\-1 & \phantom{-}3 \end{smallmatrix}\right]$.  If my interpretation above is correct, then we should have the following:
\begin{align*}
g \cdot \partial_x &= 3 \partial_x + \partial_y\\
g \cdot \partial_y &= 5 \partial_x + 2 \partial_y\\
g \cdot x &= 2x - 5y\\
g \cdot y &= -x + 3y.
\end{align*}
(Note that I have $G$ acting via inverse transpose on $x$ and $y$, since those are suppposed to play the role of the basis vectors of $V^*$.)  Here is my attempted justification for the first equation above, using $u$ and $v$ to substitute in the third line:
\begin{align*}
(g\cdot \partial_x) \cdot f(x,y) &= (g \circ \partial_x \circ g^{-1})\cdot f(x,y)\\
&= (g \circ \partial_x) \cdot f(3x+5y, \: x+2y)\\
&= (g \circ \partial_x) \cdot f(u,v)\\
&= g \cdot f_x(u,v)\\
&= g \cdot (f_u u_x + f_v v_x) & \text{(chain rule)}\\
&= g \cdot (3 f_u(u,v) + f_v(u,v))\\
&= 3 g \cdot f_u(u,v) + g \cdot f_v(u,v)\\
&= 3 f_x(x,y) + f_y(x,y)\\
&= (3 \partial_x + \partial_y)\cdot f(x,y).
\end{align*}
This is the "correct" anticipated result, but am I applying all the transformations in the correct order?

Likewise, for the third equation above (the action of $g$ on $x$), I have this so far:
\begin{align*}
(g \cdot x) \cdot f(x,y) &= (g \circ x \circ g^{-1}) \cdot f(x,y)\\
&= (g \circ x) \cdot f (u,v) \\
&= g \cdot x f(u,v).
\end{align*}
This is where I'm not sure how to finish rigorously; one one hand, $g$ should transform $f(u,v)$ back into $f(x,y)$, and on the other hand, since $g^{-1} \cdot \left[\begin{smallmatrix} x \\ y \end{smallmatrix}\right] = \left[\begin{smallmatrix} 2x - 5y \\ -x + 3y \end{smallmatrix}\right]$, I suppose that the $g$-action here transforms the "extra" $x$ into $2x-5y$?  So the final result is to multiply the original $f(x,y)$ by $2x-5y$, just as anticipated?

Is there a better way to understand the $G$-action here?

Comment: I guess one of the questions is: what does the expression $g \circ D \circ g^{-1}$ mean for a differential operator $D$? Perhaps this is obvious, but I don't understand the definition as stated (or at least I think I do, but it really needs to be spelled out).

Comment: Yes, this point may be the linchpin of the whole situation.  I assumed that the "conjugation" action in the literature refers to composition inside ${\rm End}(\mathbb C[V])$, since both $G$ and $\mathbb D(V)$ can be regarded as subsets of ${\rm End}(\mathbb C[V])$.  Basically, this is saying that the polynomial-coefficient differential operators are stable under linear change of coordinates; hence given $f \in \mathbb C[V]$, the action $g \cdot (D \cdot (g^{-1} \cdot f))$ is the same as some other $D' \cdot f$ for some $D' \in \mathbb D(V)$.

Comment: ... but in this case, I don't have much faith in the way I applied this composition explicitly above.  After all, if $g,h \in G$, then typically $(g \circ h) \cdot f(v) = h \cdot f(g^{-1} v) = f(h^{-1}g^{-1} v)$.  It's still not clear to me how to write down the similar composition $(g \circ D \circ g^{-1})\cdot f(v)$.

Comment: Right, so perhaps if for $g \in \operatorname{GL}(V)$ we write $\rho(g) \in \operatorname{End}(\mathbb{C}[V])$, and we consider a differential operators as being identified with its image inside $\operatorname{End}(\mathbb{C}[V])$, then we could write $g \cdot D = \rho(g) \circ D \circ \rho(g^{-1})$.

Comment: Ah, yes, that is better; I was a bit sloppy before.  I should be thinking $\rho(G) \subset \operatorname{End}(\mathbb C[V])$ rather than $G \subset \operatorname{End}(\mathbb C[V])$, shouldn't I?  Now, armed with this clearer understanding, I wonder how to convince myself that $G$ acts on the $\partial_i$ as standard basis vectors, and on the $x_i$ as dual basis vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Weyl algebra can be seen as $T(V^{\star} \oplus V)$ factored by the ideal generated by the elements $\phi \otimes \psi - \psi \otimes \phi$, $v \otimes w - w\otimes v$ and $ v\otimes \phi - \phi \otimes v - \phi(v)$, for all $v \in V$, and $\phi\in V^{\star}$.
Remember that $v$ is a (constant) vector field on $V$ so a differential operator, and $\phi$ is a linear function on $V$

($V = \mathbb{C}^n$, but can be any vector space over a field $k$).

Now, $G = GL(V)$ acts on $V$ ( standard) and on $V^{\star}$ (dual action) , and we have $(g\phi) (g v) = \phi(v)$, so $G$ invariates the ideal. We get therefore an action  of $G$ on the Weyl algebra of $V$.

Comment: I see; this is a better perspective.  Now, my only question is: why must $\operatorname{span}\{\partial_i\}$ be identified with $V$, and $\operatorname{span}\{x_i\}$ be identified with $V^*$ as $G$-representations, rather than vice versa?  I understand that there is a natural pairing whereby $\partial_i$ and $x_i$ are dual to each other, via the inner product $\langle \partial_i, x_j \rangle = \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x_i}$, but this alone does not give a canonical choice for "standard" vs. "dual."  What is it about the $\operatorname{End}(\mathbb C[V])$ setting which forces this choice?

Comment: I think that the most important part of this answer for me to understand is this: "$v$ is a (constant) vector field on $V$ so a differential operator."  I think that this means the following: each $v =\sum_i c_i e_i$ for $c_i \in \mathbb C$, where $e_i$ is the $i$th standard basis vector, and so naturally can be identified with the differential operator $\sum_i c_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$.  Is this fact the answer to my question, without any reference to $\operatorname{End} (\mathbb C[V])$?

Comment: There is no canonical basis of $V$, or $V^*$.  You can make a choice ( basis foc $V$, dual basis for $V^*$), and get the "standard" Weyl algebra. But any other choice is as good.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  But my confusion arises from the _specific_ incarnation of the Weyl algebra from my question -- namely, inside ${\rm End}(\mathbb C[V])$, where a standard $G$-action is already defined.  In this context, where the Weyl algebra "is" the free associative algebra generated by the $x_i$ and the $\partial_i$, with the relations you wrote above, the literature always states that ${\rm span}\{\partial_i\} \cong V$ and ${\rm span} \{x_i\} \cong V^*$ as $G$-reps, never vice versa.  Is this choice a necessary consequence of the $G$-action on $\mathbb C[V] \cong S(V^*)$?

Comment: @WQE: the choice is a pair of dual bases in $V$ and $V^*$, they being $(\partial_i)_i$ and $(x_i)_i$.  But if you see the Weyl algebra realized in an intrinsic way, then the action of $GL(V)$ on it seems more natural. Otherwise, you just have to check that the action works OK.